How to use kafka in SASL_SSL mode
I followed the kafka documentation https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_config and I could run the kafka in SASL_PLAINTEXT mode, then I wanted to use the kafka in SASL_SSL mode, so I followed the documentation https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_ssl to config the SSL, there are probably some problems in the documentation, but I finally resolved them and generated the certificates and store them in the store. The steps are something like below:
1. create keystore
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -validity 365 -genkey -keyalg RSA -storetype pkcs12

2. generate certificate-signing-requests (CSR)
# no parameter -destkeystoretype for keytool
# keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -validity 365 -genkey -keyalg RSA -destkeystoretype pkcs12 -ext SAN=DNS:localhost,IP:12.12.36.25
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -validity 365         -keyalg RSA                          -certreq -file server.csr -storetype pkcs12

3. create serial.txt, index.txt and openssl-ca.cnf file 
echo 01 > serial.txt    
touch index.txt

4. generate your CA (Certificate Authority)
# there is no openssl command for windows, you have to run it in the 'git bash' 
openssl req -x509 -config openssl-ca.cnf -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -out cacert.pem -outform PEM

5. add the generated CA to the **clients' truststore** so that the clients can trust this CA, also add it to server truststore.
keytool -keystore client.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file cacert.pem
keytool -keystore server.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file cacert.pem

6. Signing your CA
openssl ca -config openssl-ca.cnf -policy signing_policy -extensions signing_req -out server.cert -infiles server.csr

7. Import both the certificate of the CA and the signed certificate into the keystore:
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file cacert.pem
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -import -file server.cert 

Then I modified my server.properties file
listeners=SASL_SSL://localhost:9094
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN

# ssl configurations
ssl.keystore.location=/sdk/kafka_2.13-3.7.0/ssl_certs/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=******
ssl.key.password=******
ssl.truststore.location=/sdk/kafka_2.13-3.7.0/ssl_certs/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=******
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1

I started the zookeeper without problem, when I started the kafka server, I got the following error, it got into an endless loop :-(
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,154] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Node 0 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,154] ERROR [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9094) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,154] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Client requested connection close from node 0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,273] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Failed authentication with localhost/127.0.0.1 (channelId=0) (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,273] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /127.0.0.1 (channelId=127.0.0.1:9094-127.0.0.1:54581-56) (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,276] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Node 0 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,276] ERROR [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9094) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,276] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Client requested connection close from node 0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,383] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Failed authentication with localhost/127.0.0.1 (channelId=0) (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,383] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /127.0.0.1 (channelId=127.0.0.1:9094-127.0.0.1:54582-56) (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,383] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Node 0 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,383] ERROR [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9094) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,384] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Client requested connection close from node 0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,493] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Failed authentication with localhost/127.0.0.1 (channelId=0) (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2024-06-06 09:56:13,493] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /127.0.0.1 (channelId=127.0.0.1:9094-127.0.0.1:54583-56) (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)

I expected that the kafka server can startup with the SSL enabled.

For the first step 1. create keystore
A big PIT, when you are asked the following question like this, make sure you input the "localhost" or the broker's FQDN
don't be stupid to write your name, haha.
What is your first and last name?  
  [Unknown]:  localhost

And in the openssl-ca.cnf file, there is a field 'commonName', the value should be the broker's name, never write your own name stupidly like me :-(
commonName         = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or **YOUR name**)  
commonName_default = Test Name

After changing it to "localhost", I could get the kafka running normally. You can verify the connection by the following command
openssl s_client -connect localhost:9094 -tls1_2

